# PyCharm 4, Django and relative imports in SCSS (Errors)

Tags: django, sass, pycharm

I'm using [django-libsass](https://github.com/torchbox/django-libsass) and importing common variables and mixins in other apps. It's working just fine, but the thing that bothers me is I'm seeing warnings and errors in PyCharm as it can't find the other files. Isn't there some way to tell the IDE where to find those files?

[image: PyCharm screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using relative paths, which is not exactly what I wanted, but probably the best possible way.

[image]